# KeyError: 12 when using native python

Tags: python, database, keyerror

Trying to create a data structure which uses the department as the 'key' and the total number of requests for that department as the 'value' but I'm getting a key error of 12. (the console explicitly says something is wrong with

```
total_department_requests = total_for_department[products[entry]["department_id"]] + products[entry]["metrics"]["request_count"]
```

```
total_for_department = {}
for entry in products:   

   #print entry
   if entry not in total_for_department:
      #print "it's new"
      total_for_department.update({products[entry]["department_id"] : products[entry]["metrics"]["request_count"]} )
   else:
      total_department_requests = total_for_department[products[entry]["department_id"]] + products[entry]["metrics"]["request_count"] 
      # print total_department_requests
      total_for_department.update({products[entry]["department_id"] : total_department_requests })

print(total_for_department)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`entry` is not the index - it's the actual thing in the `products` array. `products[entry]` doesn't make sense when you do `for entry in products`

If you want the index, use `enumerate`.

```
for i, entry in enumerate(products):
```

Comment: Little confused. entry is my dictionary that has a key/value which im using to refer product info using the id of the product.

Comment: If `products` is a dict, then I guess `12` must not be a key in that dict

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would advise you to reformate your data. If you can't find a keyError , that means that you are making it too complicated.

Anyway, the KeyError "12" makes me think that you are trying to update an entry for a specific department id that doesn't yet exist.

In fact , you don't check if `["department_id"]` exist before updating `products[entry]["department_id"]`

Actually , now that I look at it, it seems you are checking if it doesn't exist , and if it doesn't you are updating it, rather than creating it.
Try to switch the two actions.

Maybe try

```
if products[entry]["department_id"] in total_for_department
```